# Form submit not populating form library columns (but saving does)

Tags: submit, form-library

I have an infopath form which does not update columns in a sharepoint form library on submit, but it does populate the columns when the form is saved.

Using sharepoint 2010, infopath 2010. Fields have been promoted and submit data connection has been created.
I'm sure there is something simple I am missing as when I save a filled in form it populates the library columns from the form fields, but does not do it when the form is submitted.

Comment: or is this normal for how it's supposed to work?

Comment: I had a few other users test out the form in case it was a permissions issue, inluding the IT manager, exactly the same things happens under their logins.
I saw another post the same, I don't want to hijack that thread. I have tried all the items mentioned in there like redoing the submit data connection and including the full url in the wizard instead of the library url.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found the issue.

The subsite I am using on sharepoint was originally created as a meeting site. Meeting sites file saved documents in successive folders (1,2,3,etc), the all items view was displaying everytjhing in folder 1 but the submit buttin was saving things outside that folder.

When I changed the submit data connection to submit to /my library/1/ it worked fine.

That'll teach me to recycle someones old test site rather than create from new.